# How to update the theme of highchart

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, themes

I have a following code that allows me to switch the theme of highchart between light and dark but it does not get updated. The theme only switches after refreshing the page. Is there a way to do this without refreshing it?

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    Highcharts.setOptions(getOptions(this.isLightTheme ? ThemeName.PROFESSIONAL_LIGHT: ThemeName.PROFESSIONAL_DARK));
}
```

Comment: There isn't a way to update the theme dynamically.  But, you can destroy and recreate the chart.  https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=44170

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not have `chart` variable to destroy, so I tried creating chart : Highcharts.Chart  When I try chart.destory(), it tells me it cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'destroy').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to recreate the chart to apply `Highcharts.setOptions` theme change. The simplest solution to do that in Angular seems to be conditional rendering of two `highcharts-chart` components. Example:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <highcharts-chart 
    [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
    [options]="chartOptions"
    *ngIf="isLightTheme;"
    >
  </highcharts-chart>

  <highcharts-chart 
    [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
    [options]="chartOptions"
    *ngIf="!isLightTheme;"
    >
  </highcharts-chart>

  <button (click)="changeTheme()">Change theme</button>
</div>
```

Component:

```
Highcharts.setOptions(theme2);
 
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  isLightTheme = true;

  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {...};

  changeTheme() {
    Highcharts.setOptions(this.isLightTheme ? theme1 : theme2);
    this.isLightTheme = !this.isLightTheme;
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-update-optimal-way-qge3vg?file=src/app/app.component.ts

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#readme