# How to change a theme if I select theme from dropdown in Highchart angular

Tags: highcharts, angular12

I want to change a theme for all the charts added as I change it from dropdown menu.

Please refer an image here.

I have a dropdown of themes. Below is the code. I want to change a theme for all the charts when I select a theme from dropdown. Here valueChange is my onchange event.

```
 <kendo-dropdownlist [data]="themeData" [(ngModel)]="selectedTheme" (valueChange)="valueChange($event)" class="ms-md-3 p-1 mt-3 mt-md-0"></kendo-dropdownlist>

  valueChange(e) {
    switch (e) {
      case 'Brand-light':
        theme(Highcharts);
        this.init();
        break;
      case 'Dark-unica':
        theme1(Highcharts);
        this.init();
        break;
      case 'Sand-signika':
        theme2(Highcharts);
        this.init();
        break;
      case 'Dark-green':
        theme3(Highcharts);
        this.init();
        break;
      case 'Gray':
        theme4(Highcharts);
        this.init();
        break;
    }
  }
```

this.init() contains a chart configuration.
Please refer below demo code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-synced-charts-jyjuew?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72396626/how-to-update-the-theme-of-highchart

Comment: Hi @Michał, As a question provided by you has a custom themes, I want to implement  Highcharts inbuild themes.  As you can see I have added a stackblitz example. In that I have imported Highchart inbuilt themes and calling them as dropdown value selected in valueChange method.

Comment: There seems to be some error with them: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/17635